# How do I set values in a nested map in mongoose directly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a mongoose schema which has a map(holding) nested in other map(users).

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  users: {
    type: Map,
    of: new mongoose.Schema({
      holding: {
        type: Map,
        of: Number,
      },
    }),
  },
});
const UserModel = mongoose.model('black', UserSchema);
```

I create a new user with the below info.

```
  var user = new userModel({
    users: {
      jose: {
        holding: { itc: 9, hcl: 300 },
      },
    },
  });
```

Now I am trying to edit a value in the map `holdings` for my user with the set method. Which I am able to do as below.

```
  await user.set(`users.jose`, {
    holding: { itc: 90, hcl: 300 },
  });
  user.get(`users.jose.holding.itc`) //displays new value(90)
```

However  if I try to set the values in nested map "holding" directly this does not work.

ie the below code fails(value is not set)

```
await user.set(`users.jose.holding.itc`, 1000);
user.get(`users.jose.holding.itc`) //gives old value or does not display 1000
```

Why does this fail? .How do I set values in a nested map in mongoose directly.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to paste it, but why do you `await` the assignment in the working case and not in the second case?

Comment: i had added await in my actual code will make the edit